# Hide specific (ultra-wide) image

Tags: firefox, images

Someone sent me a HTML e-mail with an embedded 3311-pixel wide image. As a consequence, gmail widens the text box accordingly, which makes the e-mail very hard to read. Is there a way to hide this one specific image, or otherwise tell Firefox to ignore it in the formatting?

I am using Firefox 11.0, and since I do not administer this machine, I cannot update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the built-in developer tools**

1. Right-click the image and select the "Inspect element" option (or press Q).
2. If it doesn't open the element tree vew, then press the second icon on the toolbar at the bottom.
3. Then simply delete the selected node by right-clicking it and selecting "Delete node" option.

You can refresh the page to restore it. (This works in most recent versions of Firefox without any extension, btw.)

EDIT:

**Using a bookmarklet**

If nothing helps, and you are not able to add extensions, too, drag this code to your bookmarks tab (it's a bookmarklet), and click it when you are on the right page.

```
javascript:(function(is){for(var i=0;i<is.length;i++){is[i].src="";}}(document.images));
```

The code goes over all images on the page, and removes their `src` attribute. A bit heavy handed, but it should work.

Comment: I don't see any "delete node" option. I guess my Firefox is too old (version 11.0; I'm not administrating this machine so I can't update it).

Comment: Delete node option appears when you right-click a node in the element tree. If it doesn't appear, you could try editing the src attribute and removing its contents, but I'm pretty sure that if you can open the node tree to begin with, there should be a delete node option.

Comment: The bookmarklet can also be run from the JS Console (Ctrl+Shift+K).

Answer (score 1):

Firebug can delete an element in the current page temporarily.